# Is it good idea to use expensive LINQ calls under heavy load?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am working with cassandra using datastax c# driver. I need to pull data out from three different tables. Below is my code which does the job.

```
    private const string itemMapStmt = "FROM product_data WHERE client_id = ? PER PARTITION LIMIT 1";
    private const string itemSelectStatement = "FROM item WHERE item_id = ? PER PARTITION LIMIT 1";
    private const string itemProStmt = "FROM process_holder WHERE item_id = ? AND process_id = ? PER PARTITION LIMIT 1";
    private var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(100);

    private readonly IResponseMapper rpm;
    private readonly Cluster cluster;
    private readonly ISession session;
    private readonly IMapper mapper;

    /**
     *
     * Below method gets data from all 3 different tables.
     *
     */
    public async Task<IList<Item>> GetAsync(IList<int> clientIds, int processId, int proc, Kyte kt)
    {
        var clientMaps = await ProcessCassQueries(clientIds, (ct, batch) => mapper.SingleOrDefaultAsync<ItemMapPoco>(itemMapStmt, batch), "GetPIMValue");

        if (clientMaps == null || clientMaps.Count <= 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var itemIds = clientMaps.SelectMany(x => x.ItemIds).Where(y => y != null).ToList();

        // 1st table
        var itemsTask = ProcessCassQueries(itemIds, (ct, batch) => mapper.SingleOrDefaultAsync<ItemPoco>(itemSelectStmt, batch), "GetAsync");

        // 2nd table
        var itemProTask = ProcessCassQueries(itemIds, (ct, batch) => mapper.SingleOrDefaultAsync<ItemProPoco>(itemProStmt, batch, processId), "GetIPValue");

        var items = await itemsTask;
        if (items.Count <= 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var itmDictionary = items.ToDictionary(dto => dto.ItemId, dto => rpm.MapToItem(dto, proc));
        var itmProDict = itemIds.ToDictionary<int, int, ItemProPoco>(id => id, id => null);
        var holder = new List<int>();

        var itemPrices = await itemProTask;
        itemPrices.ForEach(i => { if (i != null) itmProDict[i.ItemId] = i; });
        foreach (var ip in itmProDict) if (ip.Value == null) holder.Add(ip.Key);

        if (holder.Count > 0)
        {
            // 3rd table
            var ipHolder = await ProcessCassQueries(itemIds, (ct, batch) => mapper.SingleOrDefaultAsync<ItemProPoco>(itemProStmt, batch, kt.Pid), "GetIPValue");
            ipHolder.ToList().ForEach(ipf => { if (ipf != null) itmProDict[ipf.ItemId] = ipf; });
        }

        return itmDictionary.Select(kvp =>
        {
            itmProDict.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out var ip);

            if (kvp.Value != null)
            {
                rpm.convert(ip, kvp.Value);
                return kvp.Value;
            }

            return null;
        }).Where(s => s != null).ToList();
    }

    /**
     *
     * Below method does multiple async calls on each table for their corresponding id's by limiting it down using Semaphore.
     * (does below method looks right in terms of performance?)
     *
     */
    private async Task<List<T>> ProcessCassQueries<T>(IList<int> ids, Func<CancellationToken, int, Task<T>> mapperFunc, string msg) where T : class
    {
        var tasks = ids.Select(async id => 
        {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync();
            try
            {
                ProcessCassQuery(ct => mapperFunc(ct, id), msg);
            }
            finally
            {
                semaphore.Release();
            }
        });

      return (await Task.WhenAll(tasks)).Where(e => e != null).ToList();
    }

    // this might not be good idea to do it. how can I improve below method?
    private Task<T> ProcessCassQuery<T>(Func<CancellationToken, Task<T>> requestExecuter, string msg) where T : class
    {
        return requestExecuter(CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

In my `ProcessCassQueries` method, I get data out from cassandra for each `id` but I am limiting it down using `Semaphore` so that I don't put pressure on Scylla db under heavy load. I wanted to see is there anything we can do here to improve things out in terms of performance as this method will be used under very heavy load and I see lot of expensive LINQ calls like `ToDictionary`, `ToList`, `ForEach` that could be problematic under heavy load.

Anything we can improve here? If yes - can someone provide an example?

Comment: Generally speaking an I/O operation is much more time consuming then a collection creation logic. So spending effort on optimising things like that might not be beneficial.  If you want to optimize it then you have to first understand the characteristic of the current code and use it as a baseline for your further improvements and measurements.

Comment: Put your code under heavy load and see if it is too slow. If it is too slow, then profile your code and see if the linq queries are the bottleneck. And only then, if answer is yes, consider optimizing those queries.